# promise pending while performing CRUD operations even when there's no promise

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose, postman

I am trying to make a register page with email and password.
I am having a problem with the post request.
Whenever I post through postman it keeps on sending requests.
and console shows promise pending.

````
function registration()    
{
    app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
       const model = new Model({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        })
        const result = model.save();
        console.log(result);
    }) 
}
registration();```


//here's the remaing portion

`
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening to port ${port}`));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Login", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(()=>console.log('connected mfs'))
.catch((err) => console.error("error found...", err));

const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{type:String, required: true},
    password:{type:String, required :true}
});

const Model = mongoose.model('login', LoginSchema);
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.save()` function returns a promise

possible solutions

1- use async/await

```
function registration() {
  app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const model = new Model({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    })
    const result = await model.save();
    console.log(result);
  })
}
```

2- use promises

```
function registration() {
  app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const model = new Model({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    })
    model.save().then(result => console.log(result))
  })
}
```

3- use callbacks (don't recommend that though)

Also you can use `.create()` instead of `new Model({})` and then `model.save()`

like this

1- async/await

```
function registration() {
  app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const model = await Model.create({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    })
    console.log(model)
  })
}
```

2- promises

```
function registration() {
  app.post('/login',  (req, res) => {
    Model.create({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    })
    .then(model => console.log(model))
  })
}
```